# Html Safe Flash Hash in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to put a link in my flash hash.

I have setting my flash hash like this:

```
flash.now[:notice] = "<a href='http://google.com'>foo</a>".html_safe
```

And in the view I have:

```
= notice.html_safe
```

However, characters such as "<" are still escaped and the link does not work.

I can see how this may make it easier for hackers to do XSS injections. Is that the reason this is disabled? Or is there something else I must do to make this work?

Comment: Try to remove the `html_safe` from the flash declaration and just on the view keep the `html_safe`

Answer (score 1):

To unescape, you need

```
= raw notice
```

---

UPDATE

In addition to the above, please try

```
flash.now[:notice] = "<a href='http://google.com'>foo</a>"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried this and it is not working for me. I also tried = raw notice.html_safe and that didn't work either.

Comment: I modified the post. Please try it.